# Excel: Disable "Some files can contain viruses" warning when opening file links

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have a large Excel table with a lot of local file hyperlinks to PDF files. These links are clicked often, and every time a warning pops up:

> Opening <path\to\file.pdf>
>
> Some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer.
> It is important to be certain that this file is from a trustworthy source.
>
> Would you like to open this file?

This dialog is extremely annoying; is there a way to disable it?

What I've tried (none of it helped):

- In Registry, add `DisableHyperlinkWarning    REG_DWORD    0x00000001`. I've tried it under following keys:

  - `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common`
  - `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Common\Security`
  - `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common`
  - `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security`
- In Registry, enable trusted protocol via `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Common\Security\Trusted Protocols\All Applications`. No "Office" key exists under "Microsoft".
- In Registry, go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf`, and add key `EditFlags    REG_DWORD    0x00010000`
- Windows Start button ➔ Internet Options ➔ Security ➔ Trusted Sites. It is impossible to add a `file://` link to a local folder.
- Excel ➔ Excel Options ➔ Trust Center ➔ Trusted Locations. Added folder under User Locations, restarted Excel, warning still pops up.

Excel version: "Microsoft Excel for Office 365 MSO (16.0.12527.21378) 64-bit"

Comment: I don'thave Excel to test anything, but what is the source of the PDFs? If they were downloaded at some point, they may have [Alternate Data Streams specifying a Zone Identifier](https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/introduction-to-ads-alternate-data-streams/#:~:text=One%20of%20the%20legitimate%20usages,before%20it%20can%20be%20run.). Quick check in a Command Prompt with `dir /r` and look for entry pairs like `MS-SHLLINK.pdf` and `MS-SHLLINK.pdf:Zone.Identifier:$DATA`. Can post complete answer if those exist.

Comment: Try to use the [Streams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams) free app to delete the alternate data streams of all files in the folder. Use the syntax of `streams -s -d <directory>`. Take a backup of the folder before.

Comment: Another useful utility is [AlternateStreamView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html) which both GUI and command-line interfaces.

Comment: have you seen [this microsoft answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2019/disable-some-files-can-contain-viruses-or/ea037a49-3b46-4dc2-83ae-9943f87f3abc) ? They speak about deleting a registry value, which is: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\9.0\Common\Internet` And DWORD: `ForceShellExecute with Value 1` Read the whole thread as deleting that value might introduce other problems

Comment: @1NN, that key doesn't exist for me (under 16.0 instead of 9.0).

Comment: Have you tried Streams or AlternateStreamView to delete the alternate data streams of all files in the folder?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 I checked ADS (there's none) and ForceShellExecute (key doesn't exist). Problem still unsolved, but I can confirm it happens both on Excel 365 and Excel 2019 on Windows 10.

Comment: (1) Try adding `DisableHyperlinkWarning` to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Security`. (2) Try the Group Policy updates in Option Three of [this article](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html).

Comment: @harrymc, the group policy edits didn't work for me (I added .mp4 to the list), and the registry key you listed doesn't exist of me (no "Office" key exists under "Microsoft".).

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the .pdf files have Alternate Date Streams with Zone Identifiers. To check, Open a **PowerShell** window in the directory containing the files, then copy & paste this command:

```
(Get-Item *.pdf -Stream 'Zone.Identifier' -ea silent).FileName
```

If file names are returned by that command, they have ADS Zone Identifiers.

And if you want to remove them from the files:

```
Get-Item *.pdf -Stream 'Zone.Identifier' -ea silent | ForEach {
    Unblock-File -LiteralPath $_.FileName }
```

---

### More on ADS/Zone Identifiers

If you're curious, the most likely place the average user will find files with ADS is in your **Downloads** directory (Windows adds the Zone Identifer during download). you can view the information in the ADS by runnig this code from your **Downloads** directory:

```
Get-Item * -Stream 'Zone.Identifier' -ea silent | ForEach{
[PSCustomObject]@{
    'Name'   = ( Split-Path $_.FileName -Leaf )
    'ZoneID' = ( Get-Content -LiteralPath $_.PSPath -Raw )
}} | Out-GridView
```

[image: Sample output]

Also, some `.url` files (those on Desktop?) have an ADS that encapsulates a `.ico` file. If you have `.url` shortcuts on your Desktop, try the following from the **Desktop** directory:

```
gci *.url | Where { (gi $_ -Stream *).Count -gt 1 } | ForEach{ (gi $_ -Stream *).PSChildName }
```

Output:

```
PS C:\...\Desktop>gci *.url | Where { (gi $_ -Stream *).Count -gt 1 } | ForEach{ (gi $_ -Stream *).PSChildName }
CTA  Bus Tracker.url::$DATA
CTA  Bus Tracker.url:favicon
Morning Joe - Joe Scarborough, Mika Brzezinski, & Willie Geist.url::$DATA
Morning Joe - Joe Scarborough, Mika Brzezinski, & Willie Geist.url:favicon
Technet forums.url::$DATA
Technet forums.url:favicon
PS C:\...\Desktop>
```

If you want to extract at the icons:

```
gi *.url -Stream favicon -ea silent | ForEach {
    $Splat = @{
        'LiteralPath' = "$($_.FileName).ico"
        'Value'       = Get-Content -Literal $_.PSPath -Raw -Encoding Byte
        'Encoding'    = 'Byte'
        'FOrce'       = $True
    }
    Set-Content @Splat
}
```

To search a folder and its subfolders for any files with ADS:

```
Get-CHildItem -Directory -Recurse | ForEach {

    If ( ( $ADS = Get-Item "$($_.FullName)\*" -Stream * | ? Stream -ne ':$DATA' ).Count -ne 0 ) {
        $ADS | ForEach { Get-Item -Literal $_.FIleName }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried running `(Get-Item *.mp4 -Stream 'Zone.Identifier' -ea silent).FileName` but unfortunately it returned nothing. For me these are mp4 files generated with ffmpeg, rather than pdfs like the OP. So they are not from the internet. But I still get the hyperlink warning even after trying all of his suggestions.

Comment: Then it may be caused by something othat than ADS -- it was a guess based on the the error message. If you're curious, you're almost sure to find files with ADS in your **Downloads** directory. A single wildcard with no extension will check all files: `(Get-Item * -Stream 'Zone.Identifier' -ea silent).FileName`.

Comment: You're right, I was able to find something in my downloads folder. Unfortunately, the folder I'm pointing to is not that one, and even using the wildcard there still isn't a single item in there that has the ADS. So I'm really not sure what else to try at this point.

Comment: @KeithMiller My PDFs don't have ADS; but thank you for this highly interesting information - I had no idea that NTFS have this feature!

Comment: I appreciate the help with typos. Never was a great typist (almost like motor dyslexia, left hand gets ahead of right) but could see my mistakes when proofing. Now, central vision loss makes seeing whole words difficult and mistakes are easier to miss.

Answer (score 1):

The "insert hyperlink" dialogue in Office 365 looks like a Zombie from Windows XP. And if in that dialogue you click on the 'browse the web' button, astonishingly, internet explorer will open. This makes me think that probably all hyperlinks in office are routed through the internet explorer's dll, so it might have to do something with your explorer-related security settings. In fact, Office 365 uses the information bar rather than popups for security warnings, this makes me think that your popup actually is inherited from internet explorer.

I couldn't replicate your issue, but these steps might point you (or someone else) in the right direction.

Open Control panel. Click on 'Network and Internet' -> 'Internet Options'.

In the 'Internet Properties' window which opens, go to the 'Security' tab. Both on 'Local intranet' and on 'Trusted sites', set the 'Security level for this zone' to "Low". Also, untick "enable protected mode", if it is selected.

[image]

Comment: Do you know which setting specifically it is (of the settings in the "custom level" dialog)? My "Local Intranet" doesn't have the slider, so I'm not sure we have the exact same settings. But I set it to "low" for trusted sites and I'm still getting the popup in Excel, even after restarting.

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Apparently "My Computer" is a separate hidden zone and can be edited via regedit, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/ie-security-zones-registry-entries

Answer (score 0):

In the registry, I found this key:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ProtocolDefaults`
The values for each protocol are very likely Zone Idnetifiers -- it would explain files with no ADS still acting like `Zone 3` files.

[image]

Try:

1. changing the value of the `file` entry to `0` (`Computer`) or `1`
   (`Local Intranet`)
2. Restart
3. Test

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, even after restarting (I set it to 0).